# ATOMエディタを再インストールしても、再インストール前の状態が復元されてしまう

Tags: atom-editor

ATOMエディタの再インストールを簡単にできる方法を教えてください。

Atomをアンインストールして、再度インストールしても前のものが残っているので、インストールしても前の状態で再開します。いろいろサイトで調べてやってみたが、なんとかガイドウィンドウが最初に出てくるようになり、これはうまくいったと思って、エディタを使用してみると予測変換をしてくれません。ただ、黒板に書いているだけになっている状態です。•autocomplete-css、•autocomplete-htmlをインストールしてもダメです。どうすれば、初期化に戻るのでしょうか。パソコンがあまり詳しくないので、簡単に再インストールできるやり方を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/204548

Answer (score 1):

これではないですか？ 例はWindowsですが、他のOSでも同様のフォルダがあるでしょう。

[Reset to Factory Defaults](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#reset-to-factory-defaults)

> In some cases, you may want to reset Atom to "factory defaults", in other words clear all of your configuration and remove all packages. This can easily be done by opening a terminal and executing:
>
> ```
> C:\> rename %USERPROFILE%\.atom .atom-backup
> ```
>
> Once that is complete, you can launch Atom as normal. Everything will be just as if you first installed Atom.
>
> > Tip: The command given above doesn't delete the old configuration, just puts it somewhere that Atom can't find it. If there are pieces of the old configuration you want to retrieve, you can find them in the `%USERPROFILE%\.atom-backup` directory.
>
> **工場出荷時のデフォルトにリセット**
>
> 場合によっては、Atomを「出荷時の設定」にリセットしたい、つまりすべての設定をクリアしてすべてのパッケージを削除する必要があります。これは端末を開いて以下を実行することで簡単に実行できます。
>
> それが完了したら、通常どおりAtomを起動できます。あなたが最初にAtomをインストールしたかのようにすべてがなるでしょう。
>
> > ヒント：上記のコマンドは古い設定を削除するのではなく、Atomが見つけられない場所に置くだけです。取得したい古い設定の部分がある場合は、それらをディレクトリに見つけることができます。`%USERPROFILE%\.atom-backup`